# DNS propagation delay or bad configuration?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, bind

I have been waiting the DNS propagation for almost 24 hours. I'am no impatient, but I want to know if I configured my zone good or I have any error in it.

I think that is good, because if I use my server dns like my DNS secondary I can resolve and lookup host well.

```
;
; BIND data file for mydomain.net
;
$TTL    86400
@   IN  SOA mydomain.net. mydomain.net. (
        20120629    ; Serial
           10800    ; Refresh 3 hours
            3600    ; Retry 1 hour
          604800    ; Expire 1 week
         86400 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN  NS  ns1
@       IN  NS  ns2

    IN  MX  10 mail

ns1     IN  A   5.39.X.Y
ns2     IN  A   5.39.X.Z
```

There is not any errors in /var/syslog about bind daemon. Is everything correct? Do I only need to wait up to 48 hours for the right DNS propagation?

My nslookup from a remote machine with the nameserver of the bind host:

```
$ nslookup mydomain.net
Server:     bind-host-ip
Address:    bind-host-ip#53

Name:   mydomain.net
Address: domain-ip
```

Comment: If you hadn't masked your real domain we could have checked it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `dig` and specifying your nameserver using the @ notation, there is **no delay**.  As soon as you have saved the new zone file and reloaded bind it will start handing out the new information.

If you are not specifying your name servers using the @ notation, (this is what everyone else will be doing) there is most likely caching involved.  `dig` will include the current TTL in the response.

That said, I don't see any A records in that zone file.  Did you leave them out of the question or are they not in the file?

Comment: Yes, it has A records, but I omitted it. I have just update the question with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your negative cache TTL is 86400 seconds (one day) you probably just need to wait a few more hours.

The negative cache TTL is how long non-authoritative DNS servers should cache NXDOMAIN records. In other words, if a name server looks up a record that doesn't exist, how long should it cache "that doesn't exist"?

In your case, that's set to one day. What probably happened was that you queried for the record just before creating it (or just after) and the DNS server you queried now has a negative record that is waiting to expire.

You probably want to lower the negative TTL value.

Comment: Sure, I changed the TTL to a lower one. But I thought that, anyway, I have to wait for the old one expires